# PrintWriter won't work in my loops but my loops are working

Tags: java, loops, printwriter

It will print the array in the console so I know the loop is working but PrintWriter wont print anything in the file.

```
public static  void writePuzzle(char[][] puzzle, String file){

    try{
      PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter ((file)));

      for(int i= 0 ; i<puzzle.length; i++ ){   
        for(int j= 0 ; j<puzzle.length; j++ ){

          pr.print(puzzle[i][j]);
          System.out.print(puzzle[i][j]);
        }
        pr.println();
        System.out.println("");
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Include a:

```
pr.flush();
```

Just after your loop.

Comment: Thank you ! I havent learned that yet though, is there any other way?

Comment: What you do mean by you haven't learned that? It's at the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

use flush()

```
pr.flush();
```

or create autoflush PrintWriter

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(..., true);
```